# If $9 ≥ 4x + 1$, which inequality represents the possible range of values of $12x + 3?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $9 ≥ 4x + 1$, which inequality represents the possible range of values of $12x + 3$?

I've been trying to do SAT prep, and I came across this question. It allowed me to show an explanation and it still didn't make any sense to me.

"If we look closely, we see that $12x+3=3(4x+1)$."

What did they do to get $12x+3=3(4x+1)?$

The answer choices:

A. $12x+3≥17$

B. $12x+3≤17$

C. $12x+3≥27$

D. $12x+3≤27$

Thank you for your time.

Comment: They looked closely, it says. Do you disagree that $12x+3=3(4x+1)$?

Comment: Since you are given a restriction on $4x+1$, it is natural to ask what "affine" transformation would give you a restriction on $12x+3$.  It is a simple "linear" transformation (multiply by $3$) in this case, which you can begin to work out by comparing the coefficients of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$
12x+3=3(4x+1)
$$

so $12x+3\le 27$

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply both sides of an inequality by the same positive number and the inequality will still hold.

The "look-closely" part points out that you can multiply $4x+1$ by $3$ to get $12x + 3$.  Just distribute the $3$ through each term:

$$3 \cdot (4x+1) = 3 \cdot 4x + 3 \cdot 1 = 12x + 3.$$

Hence, to keep the inequality the same, you multiply the other side by $3$:

$$9 \geq 4x + 1$$
$$3 \cdot 9 \geq 3 \cdot (4x+1)$$
$$27 \geq 12x + 3$$
$$12x + 3 \leq 27$$

The last step just flips the sides to make it match the form of the choices.

(If we were multiplying by a negative number, the direction of the inequality would switch.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it the easy but harder way

$9 \ge 4x + 1$

$8 \ge 4x$

$2 \ge x$

$24 \ge 12 x$

$27 \ge 12x + 3$

But if you want to do it the hard by easier way

$9 \ge 4x + 1$

$3*9 \ge 3(4x + 1)$

$27 \ge 12x + 3$

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}{llr}12x+3 &= 1\cdot (12x + 3)&\text{due to properties of 1}\\
&=3\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot(12x+3)&\text{by replacing 1 with}~3\cdot\frac{1}{3}\\
&=3\cdot(\frac{1}{3}\cdot 12x + \frac{1}{3}\cdot 3)&\text{by distributivity of multiplication over addition}\\
&=3\cdot(4x+1)&\text{by evaluating}~\frac{1}{3}\cdot 12~\text{and}~\frac{1}{3}\cdot 3\end{array}$

Going in reverse is faster:

$3(4x+1)=3\cdot 4x + 3\cdot 1 = 12x+3$, again by the distributivity property of multiplication over addition.

In general $a(b+c)=ab+ac$